# ¿Por qué al hacer click y agregar 1 vez el producto al carrito de compras, dicho producto se suma 2 veces en vez de 1 al carrito? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, bucles, function

Comunidad, ¡los saludo! Tengo un problema realizando un carrito de compras y es que cuando agrego un producto al mismo, se duplica de inmediato, es decir, doy click y en vez de aparecer en el carrito que agregué 1 producto aparecen 2 y luego si le doy otra vez y agrego 2 aparecen 3 y así sucesivamente. Siempre se suma 1 de más. De seguro esto tiene que ver con el ciclo sobre el array de productos y cada vez que se cumple el mismo lo recorre dos veces pero he hecho múltipes pruebas y no logro dar con el error. Lo más probable es que esté en la función agregar cantidad o la función comprar. Estaré agradecido por la ayuda.

```
// FUNCION PARA GENERAR INTERFAZ DE PRODUCTOS
function productoUI(productos,id){
// EL ARRAY DE PRODUCTO GLOBALES
$(id).empty();
for (const producto of productos) {
$(id).append(`<div class="card"style="width: 18rem;">
<img src="${producto.img}"class="card-img-top"alt="..." >
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title"><strong>${producto.modelo}</strong></h5>
  <h4> ${producto.color}</h4>
      <span class="badge badge-warning"><p class="card-text">$${producto.precio}</p>  </span>
  <h6>${producto.categorias}</h6>
  <h7>${producto.marca}</h7> <br><br>
  <a href="#" id="${producto.id}" class="btn btn-primary btn-compra"  >Comprar</a>
</div>
</div>
 
 `);
 
}
const botones = $(`.btn-compra`);
for (const boton of botones) {
    boton.onclick = comprarProducto;
}

// FUNCION BOTON
}
function comprarProducto(e){
    // refresco al presionar
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // obtener id del boton presionado
    const productoID = e.target.id;
    // obtener objeto del prpducto correspondiente al ID
    const seleccionado = productos.find(p => p.id == productoID );
    if(seleccionado == undefined){
      carrito.push(productos.find(p => p.id == productoID));
    }else{
      //SI SE ENCONTRO AGREGAR UN CANTIDAD
      seleccionado.agregarCantidad(1);
    }
    carrito.push(seleccionado);

    // GUARDAR EN STORAGE
    localStorage.setItem("CARRITO", JSON.stringify(carrito));

    // GENERAR SALIDA DEL PRODUCTO
    carritoUI(carrito);
}
//   FUNCION PARA REDENRIZAR LA INTERFAZ DEL CARRITO
function carritoUI(productos){
    
$("#cantidadCompras").html(productos.length);
$("#carritoCompras").empty();
for (const producto of productos) {
 $(`#carritoCompras`).append(registroCarrito(producto)); 
  }  
// $("#carritoCompras").append(`<option>${producto.modelo} ${producto.color}  $${producto.precio}</option>`)   }
//agregamos total
$('#carritoCompras').append(`<p id="totalCarrito"> $ TOTAL ${totalCarrito(productos)}</p>`)
//   ASOCIACION EVENTOS
$(`.btn-delete`).on(`click`,eliminarCarrito);
$(`.btn-add`).click(addCantidad);
$(`.btn-sub`).click(subCantidad);
}



function registroCarrito(producto){
    return `<p>
                 ${producto.modelo}
                  
                <span class="badge badge-warning" >  $ ${producto.precio}</span>
                
                <span class="badge badge-dark"> ${producto.cantidad}</span>
                
                <span class="badge badge-light"> $ ${producto.subtotal()}</span>
                <img src="${producto.img}" alt="">
                <a id="${producto.id}" class=" btn btn-outline-dark my-0 my-sm-0  btn-add">+</a>
                
               <a id="${producto.id}" class="btn btn-outline-dark my-0 my-sm-0 btn-sub">-</a> 
                <a  id="${producto.id}" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-0 my-sm-0 btn-delete"  >x</a>
                </p>
    
   `
}
// ${producto.color}
// FUNCION ELIMINAR CARRRITO
function eliminarCarrito(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
    // eliminar con filter
    // carrito = carrito.filter(producto => producto.id != e.target.id)
    let posicion = carrito.findIndex(p => p.id == e.target.id);
    carrito.splice(posicion, 1);
    // actualizar interfaz
carritoUI(carrito);
// GUARDAR EN STORAGE
localStorage.setItem("CARRITO", JSON.stringify(carrito));
}
//MANEJADOR PARA AGREGAR cantidad 
function addCantidad(){
    let producto = carrito.find(p => p.id == this.id);
    producto.agregarCantidad(1);
    $(this).parent().children()[1].innerHTML = producto.cantidad;
    $(this).parent().children()[2].innerHTML = producto.subtotal();
    // modificar
    $("#totalCarrito").html(`TOTAL ${totalCarrito(carrito)}`);
    //GUARDAR EN STORAGE
    localStorage.setItem("CARRITO",JSON.stringify(carrito));
  }
  //MANEJADOR PARA RESTAR CANTIDAD
  function subCantidad(){
    let producto = carrito.find(p => p.id == this.id);
    if(producto.cantidad > 1){
      producto.agregarCantidad(-1);
      //$(this).parent().children()[1].innerHTML = producto.cantidad;
      let registroUI = $(this).parent().children();
      registroUI[1].innerHTML = producto.cantidad;
      registroUI[2].innerHTML = producto.subtotal();
      // modificar total
      $("#totalCarrito").html(`TOTAL ${totalCarrito(carrito)}`);
      //GUARDAR EN STORAGE
      localStorage.setItem("CARRITO",JSON.stringify(carrito));
    }
  }
  //Filtros Categorias  y Marca(Generar filtro)
  function filtroA(lista,selector){
    $(selector).empty();
    // Recorre lista
    lista.forEach(ele => {
$(selector).append(`<option value='${ele}'>${ele}</option>`);
 });
$(selector).prepend("<option value='TODOS'>Todos los productos</option>");
  }


//FUNCION PARA OBTENER EL PRECIO TOTAL DEL CARRITO
function totalCarrito(carrito){
  console.log(carrito);
  let total = 0;
  carrito.forEach(p => total += p.subtotal());
  return total;
}
```

Comment: si esto devuelve `undefined` : `const seleccionado = productos.find(p => p.id == productoID );` para que hacer esto : 
 `carrito.push(productos.find(p => p.id == productoID));`
porque haces un push si es `undefined`? no deberias validar si existe o no en carrito? no en los productos?  `const seleccionado = carrito.find(p =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás insertando el resultado de `seleccionado` independientemente de si es un producto o `undefined`, solo quita la última línea mostrada en este bloque y ya debe funcionar sin problema:

```
// Creas la variable, buscando en carrito, no en productos
const seleccionado = carrito.find(p => p.id == productoID );
if(seleccionado == undefined){
  // Si no existe en carrito, lo agregas
  carrito.push(productos.find(p => p.id == productoID));
}else{
  // Si se encontró, incrementas cantidad
  seleccionado.agregarCantidad(1);
}
// Esta línea sobra, ya insertaste o incrementaste cantidad
carrito.push(seleccionado);
```

Por cierto, ya que estás usando jQuery, podrías remplazar el siguiente código:

```
const botones = $(`.btn-compra`);
for (const boton of botones) {
    boton.onclick = comprarProducto;
}
```

Por solo esta línea:

```
$('.btn-compra').on('click', comprarProducto);
```

No es necesario crear la constante ni recorrer para asignar evento a cada botón, *jQuery* lo hace automáticamente. Referencia: [$.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Sabes @Triby que esa prueba la había hecho antes por la lógica que me comentas y no funcionó. La volví a hacer y lo que pasa es que al eliminar esa línea ya no se agrega nada al carrito y eso es lo que no entiendo. Gracias por la recomendación de simplificar el código.

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu, modifiqué la respuesta, no me di cuenta que estabas buscando en `productos` y debías buscar en `carrito`. Ahora solo quedaría verificar la función `agregarCantidad()` para ver qué hace, porque no la encontré en la pregunta.